# Blank Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to post a picture in a table view cell, but it keeps coming back blank.  I have 3 files that I've created for this.

First is a data file with the picture information:

```
import Foundation

class Data {
    class Entry {
        let filename : String
        let heading : String
        init(fname : String, heading : String) {
            self.heading = heading
            self.filename = fname
        }
    }

    let pic = [
        Entry(fname: "Picture1.jpg", heading: "Heading 1"),

    ]

}
```

Then I have my table view controller

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        let data = Data()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        }

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return data.pic.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
            let entry = data.pic[indexPath.row]
            let image = UIImage(named: entry.filename)
            cell.pic.image = image

            return cell
        }

}
```

The third is the cell itself

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var selfie: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

I have no clue why the cell is coming back blank.  I have the image file stored in Supporting Files.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would start to check if the image was loaded correctly. Fastest way to do this is to use the explicit unwrap operator. Add a `!` to the `UIImage(named:) `call. E.g.: `let image = UIImage(named: entry.filename)!` This will lead to crash if the image wasn't loaded.

Comment: The app didn't crash.

Comment: If the image was loaded correctly it's most likely a problem with the actual frame of the UIImageView. E.g. Its size is 0 or it's off screen because of wrong auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my answer:

Make sure that you registered your `UITableViewCell` subclass before calling the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method. Just add the following line into your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: I changed the name to pic in the post to make it generic.

Comment: How do you expect to get correct answers if you don't post your code correctly? Have you checked if the image is actually loaded?

Comment: I am a novice, just building my first app and am still trying to get all the rules for Stack Overflow correct as well.

Following the suggestions above, the image is not loading.  Does that mean I'm missing something in the IB?

Comment: So, you're sure that the `UIImage` instance is nil during the assigment? Then check the value of `entry.filename` before the line `let image = UIImage(named: entry.filename)` to make sure that you get the image name right.

Comment: I think my problem goes deeper than the image.  I just added a button and that doesn't show up in the table either when I run the app.  However, when I change the sizing it shows blank cells with the new size and a separator line.

Comment: Then the problem could be that you forgot to set the ReuseIdentifier of your cell in IB to "Cell"

Comment: Updated.  Still blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69576/discussion-between-andy-dewan-and-cihan-t).

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the image to the UITableViewCell's imageView

Updated Try:

> cell.selfie.image = image

instead of cell.pic.image = image

Comment: The custom class view name is "pic"

Comment: well, it's actually `selfie` in the code you have posted.

Comment: Where is the imageView in your selfie?

Comment: Even when the custom view is Selfie, what I posted should work because it is inherited from a TableViewCell

Comment: You seem to be using as the datasource array             return data.pic.count
Not as a view...

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reason:

First one is, your `UITableViewCell` contains an image view named `selfie` but you are setting `pic`.

So, try cell.selfie.image = UIImage(named: entry.filename);

Second one is, are you sure you are getting the image form `UIImage(named: entry.filename);` ?

Hope this helps.. :)